# Color that cell that is listed w/ conditional Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel

I try to find a solution in Excel with this issue. I have tried INDIRECT function but unsuccessful.  I also have visited and googled many forum pages but I couldn't find needed answer:

So. I have the list with Cells:

```
B1
B4
B7
B10
B14
etc etc on column A
```

and I wonder is there any no-macro solution to color that cell that are listed with conditional formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all the cells which MIGHT be formatted, like A1:Z100.
Use conditional formatting, Use a formula to decide which cells to format, enter this:

```
=MATCH(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),"$",""),$A:$A,0)
```

Comment: Absolute fantastic job. Yeah I have tried with ADDRESS too but this formula kick all problems away at all. BIG thanks Bob. You are my hero now.

Comment: @spriteup, just in case you always may change the accepted answer and upvote answer you found useful.

Comment: `SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()),"$","")` can be simplified to `ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),4)`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's:

- select column B
- go to home - conditional formatting - new - use a formula to decide which cells to format
- enter formula: `=MATCH("B"&ROW(),A:A,0)>0`